# Google Cloud Messaging: Can you send to a select group of users?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

For a project we need to send push notifications to the user when he/she is expected to fill in some values in our app. I thought about Google Cloud Messaging. However, we will have several locations where the user can be, and only the user in a specific location needs to receive the message.

I see no option in GCM to register with optional variables like "location:6". So, is it possible to group devices/users based on a supplied variable? Or is it only useful for sending notifications to all registered users? If so, are there alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCM does allow you to send a push message to a select group of users, but you will need to supply the list of users yourself. This means that if you only want to send a message to a group of users in a certain location, you will need to save these locations on your web server and select the users that meet your criteria.

There is a service called Xtify that lets you send push messages based on location, but I'm pretty sure that's a paid feature.

Comment: Ok, so basically I would need, after I get a reg_id from GCM, submit that id to my own server with additional data, so the server knows who to send to?

Comment: Basically. If you want to send your message to a select group of users, you will always need to supply the exact list of ID's you want to send the message to. Hence, you will always need to save all ID's somewhere so you can reference them later. If you also save location data and link it to the user ID's, you would be able to select all users that comply to your criteria. But, this is just a suggestion, I have no real idea as to how you would implement the location saving.

Answer (score 1):

maintain a db of device registration id(s) , wherein you can have a column containing groupid , and then while querying for the devices to send message to , query based on groupid , you will get device registration id(s) belonging to that group , and then you can send the message to them